# Find the point $T(a,b)$ on the curve $y = x^2$ which has the shortest distance between itself and the point $P(3,0)$ [Solution Verification]]

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, solution-verification

Find the point $T(a,b)$ on the curve $y = x^2$ which has the shortest distance between itself and the point $P(3,0)$.

$$
\\ \begin{align}
\\ y &= f(x) = x^2
\\ b &= f(a) = a^2
\\
\\ &T(a, b) = T(a, a^2)
\\
\\ x_1 &= 3
\\ y_1 &= 0
\\
\\ &P(x_1, y_1) = P(3, 0)
\\ 
\\ &D \text{ is the distance between points $P$ and $T$.}
\\ 
\\ D &= \sqrt{(x_1 - a)^2 + (y_1 - b)^2}
\\ D &= \sqrt{(3 - a)^2 + (0 - a^2)^2}
\\ D &= \sqrt{a^4 + a^2 - 6a + 9}
\\ 
\\ h(x) &= x^4 + x^2 - 6x + 9
\\ h(a) &= a^4 + a^2 - 6a + 9
\\ h'(a) &= 4a^3 + 2a - 6
\\ &= 2(2a^3 + a - 3)
\\ &= 2(a(2a^2 + 1) - 3)
\\ 
\\ 0 &= 2(a(2a^2 + 1) - 3) \text{ when $a = 1$} \implies \text{ $a$ is a critical point}
\\ 
\\ &\text{Since values of $h'(x)$ change from negative to positive as values of $x$ pass through $a$,}
\\ &\text{$1$ is a minimum point on the graph of $h(x)$.}
\\ 
\\ &\text{$D$ is at its minimum value when $D(a)$; $a = 1$}
\\
\\ &\text{Therefore, the point $T(1, 2)$ is the point which has the shortest distance between}
\\ &\text{itself and the point $P(3,0)$}
\\
\\ \end{align}
$$

I am fairly certain that $a = 1$ is the global minimum for the graph of $h(a)$, because it is the only critical point. I'm not certain how I would verify this absolutely though.

Also, to find that $h'(1) = 0$, I just looked at the function $h'(x)$ after I factored it and saw that it fit. Is there a better way to go about finding this?

I find $a = 1$ to be a minimum point, but I feel like maybe it might be important to make the connection between $a$ and being a minimum point for $h(x)$ and it being a minimum point for $D$.

Would it be accurate to say that because $D = \sqrt{h(x)}$ that the global minimum of $h(x)$ is the global minimum of $D$?

Comment: All you say is correct.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Even the things I said at the bottom? What about my question about factoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a = 1$ is the correct solution; however, the point is $T(a,a^2) = (1,1)$, not $(1,2)$ as you wrote.

To verify that $a = 1$ is the only real critical point of the function $h$, it suffices to divide $h(a)$ by the factor $(a-1)$, leaving a quadratic with no real roots.  To verify that this critical point corresponds to a minimum, the second derivative test shows that $$h''(a) = 12a^2 + 2, \quad h''(1) > 0,$$ which means $h$ is concave up at $a = 1$.

Finally, regarding the relationship between $D$ and $h$, yes:  if $h$ attains a relative extremum for some value $a$, then $D = \sqrt{h}$ also attains a relative extremum for that same value, provided that $h \ge 0$.

Comment: What about how I went about finding $a=1$ to be a root of $h'$? It seemed like a rather shoddy approach. I just factored it and essentially threw it a value $1$ and it worked out to be true. I of course recognised and gave it a looking over and could see in a certain way, but it was a much more inductive than deductive approach, of which I'm much less a fan of using.

Comment: Typically, one would first attempt to find rational roots using the rational root theorem, or just by inspection.  It just so happens that it works out nicely for this choice of $P(3,0)$, but if the question had said $P(4,0)$, the resulting cubic is irreducible.

Comment: What implications would the cubic being irreducible have for calculating its roots? Would it necessitate using the RRT, similarly to an irreducible quadratic using the quadratic equation?

Comment: If the polynomial is irreducible and of degree 3 or more, then an exact expression for the root is either tediously long to write, or in the case of degree 5 or more, not even *possible* to write in elementary closed form.

Comment: Sounds like a somewhat advanced subject. I'm still in my lower-division studies, so, apologies for my naivete.